# C# global hotkey (without the usually used global hook)

Tags: c#, hotkeys, keyboard-hook

I'm creating a program for my personal use that must react to some hotkeys. For example, when I press ctrl+win+z it must perform a certain action. At present, I can use GetKeyState() from user32.dll to detect the keypresses, however I am unable to stop them being passed to the active application. In the case of ctrl+win+z, the action I want to happen occurs, but if I am using explorer, for example, explorer will also read that as an 'undo'.

The obvious solution would be to use "SetWindowsHookEx()" (also from user32.dll), however each time I try a solution involving it (anything similar to [this site's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c) example code) I get a massive slow down the first time I use the hotkey. This is not acceptable.

I hope someone can help. I can provide more information if required.

Comment: Do you get this slow down even outside the debugger?

Comment: Yes. It is more than just a slow down... it is complete and total unresponsiveness of all programs to any input for perhaps 4 seconds. in/out of debugger changes nothing that I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) function? It's definitely easier to use than a windows hook.